# PDO prepeared statements PHP Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to php mysqli ect and i have done my best to arrange a prepeared statement function to no avail. All i get is the following Error.

Call to undefined method PDO::execute()

I donnot understand why this is happening.

The values are being passed and echo'd but i still get this error.

It does not retrieve data from database either as error is called before doing so.

Can anybody see from the code what the problem is.. iv searched about on the net ect. and the closest i got what about checking the Isset of the inputs, but i had allready done this so thats not the issue.

im baffled.

Thanks for any advice... Its probly really simple. But so am i.

```
<?php

//include('conect.php')


$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classifieds", 'root', '');


$type=$_POST['type'];   
$price=$_POST['price']; 


if (isset($type) && isset($price)) {

echo $type;
echo $price;

$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE type=? AND price=?');
$stm = $dbh->execute(array($type, $price));

if(($row = $stm->fetchObject())) {

    $type=$row['type'];
    $price=$row['price'];

    echo $type; 
    echo $price;

} else 
    { echo "none recieved"; }

} else
    {echo "invalid"; }

?>
```

Comment: Your looking for the `PDOStatement` class and not the main `PDO` class.  Typically written as `$stmt`  so `$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql)` then `$stmt->execute($args)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign `$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE type=? AND price=?');` to a variable and then call `execute()` method on it.

Example:

```
$smth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE type=? AND price=?');
$result = $smth->execute(array($type, $price));
```

That's because `PDO` doesn't have `execute` method but `PDOStatement` object resolved from `prepare` method does.

Comment: The `Object resolved from prepare` is `PDOStatement`  http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Comment: Sure!  I'm not sure why your answer was down voted, as it seems like the correct answer for the question.

Comment: Wow, i really do have alot to learn. thanks for the info guys.

Comment: @ShaneDee - your using PDO and prepared statements, so that's better then 70% of the newbies I see on here.

Comment: lol thanks m8. it took a while though.

Comment: $smth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE type=? AND price=?');
$smth->execute(array($type, $price));

$result = $smth->fetchObject();

var_dump($result);

Comment: Thanks again guys, slowley getting there. weather il remember it in the morning is another matter lol#